# KSQL Query returning unexpected values in simple aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am getting unexpected results from a KSQL query against a KTable that is itself defined by a Kafka topic.  The KTABLE is "Trades" and it is backed by the compacted topic "localhost.dbo.TradeHistory".  It is supposed to contain the latest information for a stock trade keyed by a TradeId.  The topic's key is TradeId.  Each trade has an AccountId and I'm trying to construct a query to get the SUM of the Amount(s) of the trades grouped by account.

## The Definition of the Trades KTABLE

```
ksql> create table Trades(TradeId int, AccountId int, Spn int, Amount double) with (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'localhost.dbo.TradeHistory', VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON', KEY = 'TradeId');

...

ksql> describe extended Trades;

Name                 : TRADES
Type                 : TABLE
Key field            : TRADEID
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Value format         : JSON
Kafka topic          : localhost.dbo.TradeHistory (partitions: 1, replication: 1)

Field     | Type
---------------------------------------
ROWTIME   | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY    | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
TRADEID   | INTEGER
ACCOUNTID | INTEGER
SPN       | INTEGER
AMOUNT    | DOUBLE
---------------------------------------

Local runtime statistics
------------------------
consumer-messages-per-sec:         0 consumer-total-bytes:      3709 consumer-total-messages:        39     last-message: 2019-10-12T20:52:16.552Z

(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic localhost.dbo.TradeHistory)
```

## The Configuration of the localhost.dbo.TradeHistory Topic

```
/usr/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --topic localhost.dbo.TradeHistory
Topic:localhost.dbo.TradeHistory    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01,delete.retention.ms=100,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.ms=100
    Topic: localhost.dbo.TradeHistory   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

In my test, I'm adding messages to the localhost.dbo.TradeHistory topic with TradeId 2 that simply change the amount of the trade.  Only the Amount is updated; the AccountId remains 1.

## The messages in the localhost.dbo.TradeHistory topic

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --property print.key=true --topic localhost.dbo.TradeHistory --from-beginning

... (earlier values redacted) ...

2   {"TradeHistoryId":47,"TradeId":2,"AccountId":1,"Spn":1,"Amount":106.0,"__table":"TradeHistory"}
2   {"TradeHistoryId":48,"TradeId":2,"AccountId":1,"Spn":1,"Amount":107.0,"__table":"TradeHistory"}
```

The dump of the topic, above, shows the Amount of Trade 2 (in Account 1) changing from 106.0 to 107.0.

## The KSQL Query

```
ksql> select AccountId, count(*) as Count, sum(Amount) as Total from Trades group by AccountId;
1 | 1 | 106.0
1 | 0 | 0.0
1 | 1 | 107.0
```

The question is, why does the KSQL query shown above return an "intermediate" value each time I publish a trade update.  As you can see, the Count and the Amount fields show 0,0 and then the KSQL query immediately "corrects" it to 1,107.0.  I'm a bit confused by this behavior.

Can anyone explain it?

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of KSQL are you running? Are you able to reproduce this behaviour in isolation?

Comment: is it just the zero value that is confusing, or are you expecting one single output (107.0) ?

Comment: Hi Robin.  Incidentally, I really enjoyed your talk in San Francisco (I was in the front row ;-)).  I'm running it using the docker-composel.yml file from the 5.1.0-post branch of the cp-docker-images repo.  The image is confluentinc/cp-ksql-server tagged 5.1.0.  Yes, it is the intermediate 0 value that is confusing.  I was simply expecting the next row (1|1|107).

Comment: Hey cool, glad you liked it! If you're just using Docker, can you try with tag `5.3.1` (or even `5.4.0-dist-1`) and see if you observe the same behaviour?

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Robin.  I upgraded to 5.3.1.  I repeated the test I described above and am getting the same results -- an intermediate value of 0's between two ostensibly correct aggregations.  Any ideas?

Incidentally, on an unrelated note, in the 5.3.1 version of the docker-compose.yml file, I had to change the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS line so that its reference to "localhost" was changed to "broker".  It was causing trouble with connect and/or the io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your question.  I've added an answer to our knowledge base: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/3594/files.

When KSQL sees an update to an existing row in a table it internally emits a CDC event, which contains the old and new value. 
Aggregations handle this by first undoing the old value, before applying the new value.

So, in the example above, when the second insert happens, KSQL first undos the old value.  This results in the `COUNT` going down by 1, and the `SUM` going down by the old value of `106.0`, i.e. going down to zero.
Then KSQL applies the new row value, which sees the `COUNT` going up by 1 and the `SUM` going up by the new value `107.0`.

By default, KSQL is configured to buffer results for *up to* 2 seconds, or 10MB of data, before flushing the results to Kafka. This is why you may see a slight delay on the output when inserting values in this example.  If both output rows are buffered together then KSQL will suppress the first result. This is why you often do not see the intermediate row being output.  The configurations `commit.interval.ms` and `cache.max.bytes.buffering`, which are set to 2 seconds and 10MB, respectively, can be used to tune this behaviour. Setting either of these settings to zero will cause KSQL to always output all intermediate results.

If you are seeing these intermediate results output every time, then it's likely you have set one, or both, of these settings to zero.

We have a [Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3560) to enhance KSQL to make use of Kafka Stream's Suppression functionality, 
which would allow users more control how results are materialized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If we were streaming the aggregations to a dashboard, it would be pretty confusing to the user.  I'll keep my eye on the issue. ;-)

Comment: I've added details of the config you can use in the current version of KSQL (5.3) to tune this behaviour.

Comment: That’s helpful Andrew.   I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I've moved the answer to our wiki. It can be found here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/wiki/FAQ:Aggregations#why-does-ksql-output-two-events-for-each-input-event-when-aggregating-a-table